# Why is my website deploy not working with CSS?

Tags: html, css, netlify

I tried to deploy my website directory on netlify, everything "HTML" seems to work fine but nothing that's "CSS" is shown. It does seem to be working as local host though. Does anyone know what's wrong.

```
4:54:44 PM: Creating deploy upload records
4:54:45 PM: Starting post processing
4:54:45 PM: Post processing - HTML
4:54:45 PM: Post processing - header rules
4:54:45 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
4:54:45 PM: Post processing done
4:54:45 PM: Site is live ✨
```

Comment: Did you try to clear cache?

Comment: can you send the link of website? or the html of you website

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas https://www.mohammadalafshate.ca/

Comment: @Tagi How does that work please?

Comment: Your css file is not loading or not found. Make sure that this is correct path. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../NEWW/css/style.css">`.

Comment: From my test, your path should be `../css/style.css`.

Comment: @MoMoney here the video on how I resolved your problem https://imgur.com/a/6gqvxOd, now i will put a answer

Answer (score 0):

I went to the site you linked to me,
and I opened Firefox `dev-tools`

I noticed that the link for CSS seems to be correct

Firefox's `dev-tools` has a function called `STYLE EDITOR`

and I noticed that the CSS file has been deployed,

but you got confused HTML with CSS, in fact, you wrote HTML inside CSS ...

## definitely delete HTML tags (those inside the style.css file)

here is the video on how I did https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAmKG.jpg

#### before

[image]

#### after

[image]

---

#### after the edits (style.css)

```css
    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      background: rgb(14, 30, 37);
      color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 22px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    .main {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    .card {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 75%;
      max-width: 364px;
      padding: 24px;
      background: white;
      color: rgb(14, 30, 37);
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(14, 30, 37, .16);
    }

    a {
      margin: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #007067;
    }

    a svg {
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration-color: #f4bb00;
    }

    a:hover svg path{
      fill: #007067;
    }

    p:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

#### before (style.css)

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Page Not Found</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      background: rgb(14, 30, 37);
      color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 22px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    .main {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    .card {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 75%;
      max-width: 364px;
      padding: 24px;
      background: white;
      color: rgb(14, 30, 37);
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(14, 30, 37, .16);
    }

    a {
      margin: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #007067;
    }

    a svg {
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration-color: #f4bb00;
    }

    a:hover svg path{
      fill: #007067;
    }

    p:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <p>Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.</p>
          <p>
            <a id="back-link" href="/">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill="#007067" d="M11.9998836,4.09370803 L8.55809517,7.43294953 C8.23531459,7.74611298 8.23531459,8.25388736 8.55809517,8.56693769 L12,11.9062921 L9.84187871,14 L4.24208544,8.56693751 C3.91930485,8.25388719 3.91930485,7.74611281 4.24208544,7.43294936 L9.84199531,2 L11.9998836,4.09370803 Z"/>
              </svg>
              Back to our site
             </a>
          </p>
          <hr><p>If this is your site, and you weren't expecting a 404 for this path, please visit Netlify's <a href="https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125?utm_source=404page&utm_campaign=community_tracking">"page not found" support guide</a> for troubleshooting tips.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      (function() {
        if (document.referrer && document.location.host && document.referrer.match(new RegExp("^https?://" + document.location.host))) {
          document.getElementById("back-link").setAttribute("href", document.referrer);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if this help you, i will be very happy :)

Comment: This is very helpful I wish I could upvote it, but I only have 11 reputations so they're not allowing me :( but thanks anyways!

Comment: thank you when you will have the enough reputation, remember to upvote, so other people know it helped you and the answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

I see that CSS link is broken? And I would advise to use "../css/style.css" or if you want you can separate even better if you plan bigger project separating css folder with few more folders like /main, /buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I found out that while coding on PyCharm, I have to use the directory "../NEWW/css/style.css" or else if I run local host it the CSS file wouldn't work. But when deploying or publishing I have to use the directory "../css/style.css" without the "/NEWW" in order for the CSS file to take affect.

Comment: now everything is centered, you dont write anymore HTML in CSS... good work!